# xamarin: decimal in observable collection lose comma

Tags: xamarin

I'm having a strange issue with Xamarin.Forms.

I have a model such as:

```
public class VoceDocumento
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int VoceId { get; set; }
    public int DocId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductSku { get; set; }
    public string ProdottoNome { get; set; }
    public decimal Prezzo { get; set; }
```

And in my View model I have an ObservableCollection of this model.

Now when I add an item to OC I use:

```
VoceDocumento vd = new VoceDocumento();

                vd.ProductId = SelectedProdotto.Id;
                vd.ProductSku = SelectedProdotto.Sku;
                vd.ProdottoNome = SelectedProdotto.Nome;
                vd.Prezzo = Convert.ToDecimal(SelectedProdotto.Prezzo + (SelectedProdotto.Prezzo / 100 * SelectedProdotto.ScontoA));
                vd.Sconto = CalcolaScontoPercentualeFinale();
                vd.Netto = vd.Prezzo - (vd.Prezzo / 100 * vd.Sconto);
                vd.Totale = vd.Netto;
                vd.Qta = 1;
                vd.Iva = SelectedCliente.IvaPercentuale;
                vd.EsenzioneIva = SelectedCliente.IvaEsenzione;
                vd.EsenzioneIvaTesto = string.Empty;
                vd.prodotto = SelectedProdotto;

                ObCoVociDocumento.Add(vd);
```

The problem arises when I loop through this OC (to get totals) and I get that the price (Prezzo) that is supposed to be 1,50 is stored as 150.

If I use List I get correct values stored.

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: this is most likely a result of using mixed-types when calculating the value `Prezzo`, as well as using `ToDecimal` on the result.  I'd carefully step through every part of that calculation to verify that it is working as expected

Comment: I have added ToDecimal after having finished any other option... I have also tried to set vd.Prezzo = 1.5M; and I keep getting 150. Also SelectedProdotto.Prezzo/ScontoA are decimal too.

Comment: please provide samples of all values used in the calculation, the expected result, and the actual result

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your time. Here are values for *vd.Prezzo = SelectedProdotto.Prezzo + (SelectedProdotto.Prezzo / 100 * SelectedProdotto.ScontoA);* : **vd.Prezzo = 4.5 + (4.5 / 100 * 125);**. When I loop my OC Prezzo should be 10.13 instead I get 1013. This behavior doesn't happen using List<>

Comment: @Jason Weirdness upon weirdness when I changed XAML markup from Entry to Label for Prezzo I started getting the expected value